# Unbound not forwarding query

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

I'm having some trouble getting Unbound to forward queries correctly.

My current `unbound.conf` looks something like this:

```
  forward-zone:
      name: "google.com"
      forward-addr: 8.8.8.8

  forward-zone:
      name: "."
      forward-addr: 127.0.0.1@1066  # An Unbound server with a single catchall 

  remote-control:
      control-enable: no
```

The 'google.com' zone returns correctly but the catch all zone doesn't. (Even though the query appears to be received and returned correctly on the 2nd unbound server)

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem, after searching I found the solution at the mailing list *unbound-users*: [[Unbound-users] forwarders problem](https://unbound.net/pipermail/unbound-users/2014-July/003427.html). Simply set:

```
do-not-query-localhost: no
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the above config option needs to be set in the `server:` section of the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused, are you trying to query another server or the localhost on port 1066? If the latter you need to use the IP address that you have set under the interface portion of the config.

```
server:
     interface: <real ethX IP>

forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: <real ethX IP>@1066
```

Unbound won't let you query localhost/127.0.0.1 by default.